# Cannot install Terratec Piranha USB stick

Tags: drivers, usb, dvb-t

I have a relatively old DVB-T stick named Terratec Piranha. Plugging it in Ubuntu 16.04 gives the following error:

```
[ 4688.982056] usb 2-1: new full-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[ 4689.110986] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=187f, idProduct=0010
[ 4689.110989] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 4689.110991] usb 2-1: Product: SMS 1000
[ 4689.110992] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Siano
[ 4689.111530] smsusb:smsusb_probe: board id=13, interface number 0
[ 4689.111604] smsusb:smsusb_probe: board id=13, interface number 1
[ 4689.111926] smsusb:smsusb_probe: stellar device in cold state was found at usb\2-1.
[ 4689.111943] usb 2-1: Direct firmware load for dvbt_bda_stellar_usb.inp failed with error -2
[ 4689.111946] smsusb:smsusb1_load_firmware: failed to open 'dvbt_bda_stellar_usb.inp' mode 4, trying again with default firmware
[ 4689.111954] usb 2-1: Direct firmware load for dvbt_bda_stellar_usb.inp failed with error -2
[ 4689.111956] smsusb:smsusb1_load_firmware: failed to open 'dvbt_bda_stellar_usb.inp' mode 4
[ 4689.111958] smsusb:smsusb_probe: Failed to put stellar in warm state. Error: -2
[ 4689.111962] smsusb: probe of 2-1:1.1 failed with error -2
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Before anything else, search and open Additional Drivers. Additional proprietary firmware for your tuner can be listed there. If so, select and apply. Reboot.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the driver was not listed in the prioprietary "additional Drivers" section of Ubuntu. After some search, I found this post [suggesting that the firmware must be downloaded manually from the original firm](https://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/TerraTec_Cinergy_Piranha#Firmware). Unfortunately the original FTP server is down, so one should do it from a mirror/backup [server for old Terratec drivers](http://terratec.ultron.info/), as suggested [in this forum post in German](https://forum.digitalfernsehen.de/threads/hilfe-terratec-ftp-down.257986/)

```
wget http://terratec.ultron.info/Receiver/Cinergy_Piranha/Update/Cinergy_Piranha_Drv_Vista_XP_3.09.02.00.exe
unzip -j Cinergy_Piranha_Drv_Vista_XP_3.09.02.00.exe "Cinergy Piranha/BDA Driver 3.09.02.00/Windos XP (32Bit)/SMS100x_Dvbt.inp"
sudo mv -i SMS100x_Dvbt.inp /lib/firmware/`uname -r`/dvbt_bda_stellar_usb.inp
```

What we do here is that we download the compressed batch with drivers, we uncompress the firmware and we put it in the driver directory of the current linux kernel

Then unplug and re-plug the usb-stick